# 3DPlot gluing several tubes

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

How can I use Mathematica to plot the 3D figures like the following one
[image]

and its generalizations to gluing multiple tubes in a nice way. The lines and labels on the tubes are irrelevant.

If it is possible, I also want to know how to draw the figures that cut the tubes such as the following one
[image]

Comment: related: [math/hole in a hole in a hole](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2167479/421326)

Comment: As per the linked math.se question, this really is about parametrizing surfaces and does indeed not belong here. But I suggest we don't rush to migrate it to math.se, but simply close this one; the OP can then ask how to parametrize these surfaces over on math.se him/herself and can come back with questions about MMA code here later if s/he runs into problems.